# Anyone know how to hide individually Like, Comments, Views or Save for later from Socialbar on SharePoint Online SitePages?

Tags: sharepoint-online

There is way to hide SocialBar but can't find how to hide individually Like, Comments, Views or Save for later from SitePages on SharePoint Online.

Comment: check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241102/modern-site-page-hiding-total-page-views-and-like-option-in-office-365-sp-onli